# Script to export

Tags: php, mysql, linux, scripting, cron

I have a typical ubuntu setup and a mysql database. I'm trying to find a way to set a cron job to export each table in the mysql db into individual .csvs into a folder on the server.  I'm not entirely sure how to approach this, everything I've finding shows how to take multiple csvs into a mysql db but not the other way around.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can do it with `mysqldump`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find anything on using mysqldump to create individual .csvs per table

Comment: either im confused or you dont search very hard `mysqldump db_name table_name  -T --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=, > table_name.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MySQL command line cliet to execute a command something like

```
select * from someTable into outfile 'somFile.csv' 
  fields optionally enclosed by '"' terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Stick that in an SQL script file (with additional SELECTs if appropriate) then you can execute:

```
mysql -u username --password=******** < sqlscript.sql
```

Add that command to `cron` with `crontab -e` and you should be done.

A couple of gotchas: 
 - make sure the user  that cron is executing as has appropriate rights to the filesystem
 - the mySQL user you're logging in as will need `FILE` privilege
 - you might need some extra commands to move the CSV files about after they're created.

Comment: mysqldump would be easier from the command line